# 1" x 2" Furring Strips for Drywall Ceiling

Tags: drywall, basement, joists, carpentry

In my basement, there's currently a tile ceiling that's installed on furring strips attached to the joists. The furring strips are 1"x2", attached to the joists by nails. We're currently replacing the wood paneling with drywall, and would like to replace the ceiling tiles as well. Would these 1x2" furring strips be strong enough to support drywall hung from the ceiling? Generally, I've seen references to using 1x3" furring strips, so I wanted to see about the weight issue.

Comment: What is the spacing of the floor joists? Is it so wide that you need the furring strips?

Comment: @mikes - I actually didn't measure the joist spacing specifically as the furring strips allow for some wires and one small copper pipe to cross, hence I figured I would leave the furring strips in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weight isn't going to be your issue here. 2 inch furring strips may be pretty hard to hit with the drywall screws. The screws need to be in good solid wood and not going through an edge etc.  If You are careful, caulk some good lines, the 1X2's might work for ya.  The other consideration is if the spacing is good and you have enough surface to butt pieces of drywall together and still have wood to screw into.  I'd probably plan on adding some extra 1X3's to the mix to be sure you have good wood to catch a screw.

Comment: Also, use drywall adhesive. But you're definitely going to want additional wood where you have joints. I'm guessing Shirlock meant "chalk" lines rather than caulk lines above - What I have done with 1x3 (slow, but accurate) is to mark the face of the last sheet, then hoist the next sheet into place, and mark pencil lines on the face of the sheet to be sure I hit the wood. Chalk lines could do the same, I find them slightly more awkward to work with around the drywall jack I use, as a one-man crew.

Comment: You are right, I meant chalk line..  my bad..  if you put a pencil mark or some painters tape on the wall where the strapping is, you can use that as a reference for a chalk line after you raise the sheet and grab it with a few screws. Also the measure and mark before it goes up works well too.  Drywall glue is a great idea on ceilings as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the comments. Regarding drywall glue, is the idea to get a good strip of adhesive on those furring strips, and then screw them in as well to make sure there's a good solid anchor on the ceiling?

Comment: yep, that's the plan. Make sure you got a good backer at the joints.

Comment: Cool, thanks again. I realized that existing furring strips are 12" on center, so my thought, too, is those two extra furring strips per eight foot sheet will give a little extra support.

Answer (score 0):

If the existing furring strips are nailed in ,i would would try to add a 1 5/8" screw on at least every other joist for addition weight support